# how to know if admin in PHP mysqli login page

Tags: php, mysql, authentication, mysqli

i have a php login page and mysql table ( USERS : id,username,password,admin )

the admin column's data type is BIT and the default is 0 , if admin the value of users.admin= 1

so my php code is working perfectly except i dont know how to fetch the admin in my prepared statement because it is not an input like username or password :\

```
        $username='blabla';
        $password='blabla';
        if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE username=? and password=? LIMIT 1"))
     {
        /* bind parameters for markers */
        $stmt->bind_param("ss",$username,$password);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($username,$password);
        $stmt->store_result();
            if($stmt->num_rows == 1)  //To check if the row exists
                    {
                        while($stmt->fetch()) //fetching the contents of the row

                          {$_SESSION['username'] = $username;
                          //$_SESSION['admin'] = $admin; (not added yet)
                           echo "1";
                           exit();
                           }
                    }
            else {
                echo "2";
                return;
                 }

        $stmt->close();
        $stmt->free_result();
    }

    $mysqli->close();
```

Comment: Use `$row = $result->fetch_assoc()` to get the row, and then access the `admin` field

Comment: would you please show me and example :(
i am confused about accessing the admin field :\

Comment: If there's only those columns in the DB I think you can use bind it in the result. I can't test it, but something like this -> http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/6cdrw7k3/

Comment: and do i need to add it in the prepared query ?

Answer (score 0):

you can do it by session.

firstly set a session in login page 
you need the use foreache your datas in a array 
just you can see it if you use this command

```
if($stmt->num_rows == 1)  //To check if the row exists
                    {
$a=$stmt->fetch();
die(r_print($a));
```

and you will see the colum name

you can set the sessşons and variables

```
like $admin =$a[0]["colum name"];


      if($admin==1)
$_SESSION["usertype"]="admin";
```

and check if admin logined  start your code

```
    if($_SESSION["usertype"]=="admin"){
    //write your code here 
//only admin can see these part

    }
```

Comment: my question wasnt about that 
i am confused about is the admin column fetched even if i dont put it in the query ? 
id if it fetched how do i put its content in a php variable

Comment: your data comes but in a array so you can get it like $a=$stmt->fetch(); if the array comes  you can pass second part